# SVN Ignored folder shows again and again

Tags: java, svn, tortoisesvn

I have a local SVN folder which has many files/directories/sub-directories

One of them is Project-Ear, which contains generated folders/files that I do not wish to check-in at all..

I have marked this Project-Ear folder as "unversion and add to ignore list"

Now every time, I do SVN Commit, this folder Project-Ear and it's files show in the Commit dialog.

How do I fix this? I do not want this Project-Ear to be shown at all.

Answer (score 0):

If the files were initially committed into the repo, you will need to commit the "un-version" part, at that point they will be removed from the repo, and ignored from then on local file systems.